# BuildSessionFactory from FluentNHibernate hanging after applying KB3122648 update

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

After applying [MS16-019 security update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3122648), FluentNHibernate 1.1 fails to build session factory - it's just hanging on BuildSessionFactory call.

NHibernate logging interrupts before mapping XML:

```
[1] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Environment - NHibernate 2.1.2.4000 (2.1.2.4000)
[1] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Environment - hibernate-configuration section not found in application configuration file
[1] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : lcg
[1] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Environment - Using reflection optimizer
```

So it looks like it is hanging either on reflection optimiser part (which I tried to disable **) or at point when reading/applying XML mapping.

** - `ExposeConfiguration(x => x.SetProperty("use_reflection_optimizer", "false"))`

In working scenario (before applying MS16-019 update), "Using reflection optimizer" is followed by:

```
[1] DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - Mapping XML:
<hibernate-mapping...</hibernate-mapping>
[1] INFO  NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect - Using dialect: NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect
```

My guess is that mapping xml becomes invalid after fixes from MS16-019, but how I can find out what exactly is wrong and what FluentNHibernate version has fix for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I recompiled NHibernate libraries locally with additional logging I was able to find that hang occurs at [SelectNodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectnodes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) call in [ClassExtractor.GetClassEntries](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/2.1.x/src/NHibernate/Cfg/ClassExtractor.cs). The issue was fixed starting from NHibernate 3.3.x.